# edit text/srt file

Tags: linux, text-processing, editors

I have a .srt file like this

**Input File**

```
1
00:00:17,920 --> 00:00:21,159
The essential is invisible to the eye. 3

2
00:00:21,160 --> 00:00:22,559
This phrase comes from 4

3
00:00:22,560 --> 00:00:25,039
As if saying goodbye saddens me, 5
```

You can see after each dialogue there is a number (like 3 after '...eye.' , 4 after '...from'). I want to remove those numbers.

**Expected output File**

```
1
00:00:17,920 --> 00:00:21,159
The essential is invisible to the eye.

2
00:00:21,160 --> 00:00:22,559
This phrase comes from

3
00:00:22,560 --> 00:00:25,039
As if saying goodbye saddens me,
```

Is there any smart way to delete those numbers? I am using Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: [Do not upload images of input/code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Use plain text instead.

Comment: Ok, But is that against guidelines?

Comment: Do you want to remove the whitespace before the target digit(s) as well?

Comment: "_is that against guidelines?_" - yes, it is. See [PSA: Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### With `Perl`:

##### Input file:

```
1
00:00 --> 00:00
foo bar 10
    
2
00:00 --> 00:00
base qux 11
    
3
00:00 --> 00:00
aqw zdv 12
```

##### Command:

Perl `--version` >= 5.36:

```
perl -g -pe 's/\d+(?=\n\s*\n)//g' file
```

Perl `--version` < 5.36:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\d+(?=\n\s*\n)//g' file
```

##### Output:

```
1
00:00 --> 00:00
foo bar 

2
00:00 --> 00:00
base qux 

3
00:00 --> 00:00
aqw zdv
```

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `\d+` | digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `(?=` | [look ahead](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Lookaround-Assertions) to see if there is: |
| `\n` | '\n' (newline) |
| `\s*` | whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `\n` | '\n' (newline) |
| `)` | end of look-ahead |

Comment: can you do it with python/c/c++?

Comment: Perl is on most Unix system as well. This conciseness require Perl or Ruby.

Comment: ok done. Thanks

Comment: To remove the whitespace before the target digits I'm guessing that would be `perl -0777 -pe 's/\s*\d+(?=\n\s*\n)//g'` ?  Thx!

Comment: This will fail if there's a digit in among the words. Imagine `aqw 15 minutes zdv 12` ...

Comment: @tink `aqw 15 minutes zdv 12` works fine here (Perl v5.34.1).

Comment: Fails with `v5.30.0`

Comment: @jubilatious1 ... and also fails with `v5.36.0` ... it retains the 12 at the end. Are you sure it works for you? Tested on a debian 12 box just then.

Comment: Code tested as well.

Comment: @tink MacOS Ventura 13.6 here, Perl `v5.34.1`.  Works fine. Can you narrow the issue down a bit? Does `perl -0777 -pe 's/\d+(?=\n\n)//g'` work?

Comment: @jubilatious1 OK, my first attempt was on Ubuntu 20.04, the second on Debian 12, and now I tried on my notebook (Ventura 13.6.1) and it doesn't do the right thing, either. I wonder what magic you're working ... look at this image paste, and how it retains the trailing number when there's a number amidst the text [fail](https://pasteboard.co/1xr5W89JMQhQ.png) ...

Comment: Ummm ... nope. The test data was copy and pasted from here, and definitely has a new line at the end of the last line, can provide you a screenshot of `cat -vet` @jubilatious1 And the 2&3rd awk solutions work just fine with that file.

Comment: @tink That's not an issue with an internal digit among the words: it appears your test file has either 1. an incomplete last line, or 2. only a single newline at the end of the file. Others (e.g. @GillesQuénot) can chime-in regarding Unix/Linux end-of-file newline requirements, but the following updated Perl answer seems to work: `perl -0777 -pe 's/\d+(?=\n\n|\n$)//g'`. Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Using `GNU awk`

```
$ awk '/\s+[0-9]+\s*$/{NF--}1'
$ awk '{sub(/[[:space:]]+[0-9]+[[:space:]]*$/,"")}1'
```

Or

```
$ awk '/[[:alpha:]]+/ && $NF ~ /^[[:digit:]]+$/{$NF=""}1' file
```

Comment: #2 & 3 work even w/ embedded digits in the text...

Comment: @tink Edited. Please tell me if it's not working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using any sed in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ sed 's/ [0-9]*$//' file
1
00:00:17,920 --> 00:00:21,159
The essential is invisible to the eye.

2
00:00:21,160 --> 00:00:22,559
This phrase comes from

3
00:00:22,560 --> 00:00:25,039
As if saying goodbye saddens me,
```

You can do the same with any awk if you prefer:

```
awk '{sub(/ [0-9]*$/,"")}1' file
```

I only used the first 3 blocks of the OPs sample input to test with as the rest of the input is just more of the same and so just clutters the example.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -e 'for slurp() { print S:g/ \s* \d+ <?before \n\s*\n > //};'  file

#OR:

~$ raku -e 'print S:g/ \s* \d+ <?before \n\s*\n > // for slurp();'  file
```

Above are answers coded in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. Basically I've re-written @GillesQuénot's excellent Perl answers in Raku. Raku has a function `slurp` which allows you to read an entire file into memory all at once, preserving `\n` newlines, etc. (similar to Perl's `-0777` command-line option). Then it's easy to use Raku's version of a positive look-ahead, here spelled as `<?before \n\s*\n >` (Raku is whitespace-tolerant, so you can space out the Regex atoms).

There's often confusion about return values with substitution operators. Raku takes the avenue of providing a "big-S" `S///` operator which *returns the resultant string.* Also, it should be noted that in Raku, Regex modifiers like `:global` or `:g` go at the head of the operator, not afterwards as in Perl.

Note: without knowing more about `.srt` file specifications, it's probably safer to use the Raku `<?before [\n\s*\n | \n$] >` look-ahead, which will properly edit lines even if they are the *last complete `\n`-terminated line of the file* (thanks to @tink for pointing out this issue in a comment).

Sample Input:

```
1
00:00 --> 00:00
foo bar 10

2
00:00 --> 00:00
base qux 11

3
00:00 --> 00:00
aqw zdv 12
```

Sample Output:

```
1
00:00 --> 00:00
foo bar

2
00:00 --> 00:00
base qux

3
00:00 --> 00:00
aqw zdv
```

---

Another approach in Raku is using `<( … )>` Capture markers:

```
~$ raku -e 'for slurp() { print S:g/ <( \s* \d+ )> \n\s*\n //};'  file

#OR:

~$ raku -e 'print S:g/ <( \s* \d+ )> \n\s*\n // for slurp();'  file
```

Without knowing more about the target file it's hard to present further approaches. Perl has a "paragraph mode" which can be replicated in Raku with `.split(/ \n ** 2..* /)`. If every "paragraph" is 3 lines Raku has `rotor` and `batch` functions to treat them as a unit. Raku also has "flip-flop" operators for less-regular paragraphs. See the links below for starting points.

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes
https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Capture_markers:_%3C(_)%3E
https://raku.org